# If a polynomial function is raised by a different polynomial function, what's the result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let's say f(x) and g(x) are both polynomial functions.

If f(x) is raised to g(x), would the result still be a polynomial function?

I would argue that it is, since a polynomial times a polynomial is still a polynomial, which in this case, f(x) is multiplied g(x) times and thus must also result in a polynomial.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Think about some fairly simple cases.  Is $2^x$ a polynomial?

Comment: You can conclude that $f(x)$, $f(x)^2$, $f(x)^3$ and so on are all polynomials since the product of polynomials are polynomials. But the exponent has to be a positive integer, since $f(x)^{g(x)}$ cannot in general be represented as a product of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Both $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1/2$ are polynomials but $f^g=\sqrt{x}$ which is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

For example let $f(x)=g(x)=x$, we can see $f^g = x^x$ which is exponential. And a huge exponential at that.

Also $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=-1$. $f^g = x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}$. Not a polynomial either.

I think $f^g$ will be a polynomial iff $f$ is a polynomial and $g$ is a positive integer. But I may be wrong about this.

Edit: What I wrote isn't true either. $f(x)=2$ and $g(x) = \log (x)$ also gives $f^g = x$, a polynomial.